# Check for empty values in a redis datastore?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, redis, nosql

In my redis datastore I want to iterate through a set of keys and check for empty values. ie Keys which have value as an empty string. ("").

Is there any method to do that? Is there any way to combine different commands in redis to achieve the desired result in redis client?

I have seen that SCAN command is helpful in iterating over a set of keys, but it doesn't check for values.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Define "empty value". Is it empty string `""`, or non existing key that returns `(nil)`?

Comment: OP should have made more of an effort to see this question through. Don't ask a question if you don't want to get an answer.

Answer (score -2):

Using a redis-client a redis instance will be empty if you run keys * and get no results.

In Command line

```
Keys *

(empty list or set)
```